# 2nd vga monitor not being detected shows 100% black screen

Tags: drivers, ati, multiple-monitors, display

Hey guys my 2nd monitor is on but is just showing a black picture. my main monitor is connected to the video card (Amd 280) whereas the 2nd monitor i connected to the motherboards VGA port the VGA port is enabled in the bios so im not sure what is causing it not to be detected

Here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP9 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9     50.0     60.1     60.0  
   1776x1000      50.0     59.9     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1360x1024      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       60.0  
   1280x960       75.0     60.0  
   1280x900       75.0     60.0  
   1360x768       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x768       59.8  
   1280x720       50.0     60.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.0     60.0  
   1152x648       50.0     59.9  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   848x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x480        60.1     60.0     60.1     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
DFP10 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If you need any other outputs let me know.

Comment: The graphic card thinks that `CRT1` is off. Have you tried `xrandr --output CRT1 --auto`?

Comment: I just tried it then and got nothing the monitor works fine in windows as a 2nd monitor as well as during bootup as it shows the grubs menu